# How to calculate the tax rate based on the total, and tax value?

Tags: algorithm

In an e-commerce system how do I calculate what tax rate was used (e.g. 20%, 17.5%, etc) based on the total order value, and the total tax value.

For example, if I have total order value of £60 and a total tax value of £10, how do I calculate that the tax rate is 20%? (Going forward, the pre-vat total is £50 x 1.2 = £60)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing the forward calculation in reverse?

```
60 / (60 - 10) - 1 = 0.2  (i.e. 20%)
```

Comment: Thank you @Henry I got the same answer as you posted - 
`pv = 60;
va = 10;
rate = ((pc / (pc-va))-1)*100; /* rate = 20% */`